# Map my sub domain to other mai domain

Tags: php, dns, cname

i need a help i want to map http://seaspa.prouses.com with http://zoje.in with the help of CNAME Records in DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CNAME for *seaspa.prouses.com* that points to *zoje.in*, however, that would not change the URL in the users browsers. It also requires that the webserver for *zoje.in* knows it should respond to request from *seaspa.prouses.com*.

Note that you cannot have other DNS records co-existing with CNAME, so you can't have both a CNAME and MX for *seaspa.prouses.com* for instance.

If what you are looking for is a behaviour where the user enters *seaspa.prouses.com* into their browser, and then gets redirected to *zoje.in*, then you will neet to setup a URL forward or redirect or similar. Some DNS providers have functionality to do that, some don't.